# Is there a simple and clean way to develop and test collaborative Spotify Platform applications?

Tags: spotify

I have an application I am building for the Spotify Platform that involved communication among individual users of the application. I can not simply have friends download my code and test it unless they are developers. I could create two accounts and have each be a developer. Of course that would involve creating a fake Facebook account against their terms of service. Even if I do this for development, how do I do I share this with my family and friends to get feedback without them applying for a developer account?

What is best practice for developing and testing a collaborative Spotify Platform application?

UPDATE: It looks like Facebook doesn't explicitly not allow multiple accounts by an individual anymore. It simply says: "You will not create more than one personal profile."

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, find a friend or family member that is willing to fill out the simple form to be a spotify developer :-)